# Beautifoulsoup .getText() eror

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
for teknik in teknik_ayrıntılar:
detayler = teknik.find_all("tr")
    for i in detayler:
        teknik = i.find("th",attrs={"class":"prodDetSectionEntry"}).get_text()
        değer = i.find("td",attrs={"class":"a-size-base"}).get_text()
        print(teknik +"="+ değer)
```

When I write "teknik.get_text()" and "değer.get_text() python send this eror
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'"

Do you know that?

I'm using Python 3.7.3.

Comment: Please consider the `indention's` in python. In your `for` loops it is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) says, if that error happens, there is no tag matching your query.